# Best way to load static files inside AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-serverless

Im writing a serverless applications(aws lambdba and sam) to do some data transformation wherein I pass a list of jsons to my api and it updates the keys based on my mapping file which can lie inside s3 and returns the update list of jsons

What is the best way to load a mapping file within lamda? coz the file read happens everytime my lambda func is called. I dont want to hit a million times to get the same info, is there a way I can cache the info where I only reload the file only if I want to

Comment: Yes, you can cache it by keeping the contents of the mapping in some variable outside the lambda handler in some kind of global scope (in terms of the single lambda execution environment). https://blog.devgenius.io/aws-lambda-caching-why-and-how-bd3c2d500c https://theburningmonk.com/2019/10/all-you-need-to-know-about-caching-for-serverless-applications/

Comment: Great thanks, Let me try this

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple way to do that.
You can download the file and store it inside the `/tmp` folder. That way, you can check whether the file exists otherwise, download it from S3. This folder is shared across the same lambda execution environment.

The other possibility, is to have the json content stored as part of lambda environment variables (4KB max) or as part of Parameter store in SSM (4KB limit as well).

Finally, you can also attach EFS storage to lambda. That can be shared across different lambda execution.

Comment: No need to actually write it into /tmp, just keep it in a global variable and save the IO overhead.

Comment: well there is no mention about the size of the json, if it is big, you might want to keep it stored.

Comment: Got it.. I'm trying @luk2302 answer.. Think is a pretty good solution